# angularjs login with headers

Tags: angularjs, authentication, header

I am facing login problem below is my code

```
'use strict'; 

angular.module('Authentication')
.factory('AuthenticationService',['Base64', '$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
    function (Base64, $http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
        var service = {};

        service.Login = function (username, password, callback) {

        $http.post('https://www.test.com/user/Api/Securelogin',
                    { username: username, password: password },
                    {headers: {
                        access_token : 'sdfy4b9clyzstmozj75',
                        client_id : 'sdsdf_123_APP',
                        client_secret : 'sdfz78tf6j1l2dxilxx'
                    }
            })
                .success(function (response) {
                    callback(response);
            });


        };

        service.SetCredentials = function (username, password) {
            var authdata = Base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
            alert("I am not geting username and password here or authdata");
            $rootScope.globals = {
                currentUser: {
                    username: username,
                    authdata: authdata
                }
            };

            $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + authdata; // jshint ignore:line
            $cookieStore.put('globals', $rootScope.globals);
        };

        service.ClearCredentials = function () {
            $rootScope.globals = {};
            $cookieStore.remove('globals');
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ';
        };

        return service;
    }]).factory('Base64', function () {....});
```

I am using 
https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-authentication-example
Please help and suggest.

Thank you

Comment: do you wanted us to guess your problem?

Comment: I have tried a lot if you can please help

Comment: alert("I am not geting username and password here or authdata");

Comment: Did you include the authentication service js file in your html file? What is the error you are getting in console ? By the way, its not alert, it is console.log that you should use to check the values there. ;)

Comment: yes yes I am using
 https://github.com/cornflourblue/angular-authentication-example

Comment: you can get all the code just i have added headers thats it

Comment: Naga sandeep that i know to tell you i have written like that. thank you